# Change Popup Menu Position In MpAndroid Bar Chart On Value Selected

Tags: java, android, bar-chart

I want to Change position of popup menu on value selected event in Bar chart. The popup menu always displays on top. I want that popup menu to display near the item selected in bar chart .

Barchart.java

```
package com.example.saravanakumars.spinnerchart;

/**
 * Created by saravanakumars on 9/18/2017.
 */
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartValueSelectedListener;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class barchart extends AppCompatActivity  {
    BarChart chart ;
    ArrayList<BarEntry> BARENTRY ;
    ArrayList<String> BarEntryLabels ;
    BarDataSet Bardataset ;
    BarData BARDATA ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bar_chart);
        chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);

        BARENTRY = new ArrayList<>();

        BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

        AddValuesToBARENTRY();

        AddValuesToBarEntryLabels();

        Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY, "Projects");

        BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels, Bardataset);

        Bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        chart.setData(BARDATA);

        chart.animateY(3000);

//        chart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//
//
//            }
//
//        });


        chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener( new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {



                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(barchart.this,chart);

                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());


                popup.show();

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(barchart.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {

            }
        });


    }

    public void AddValuesToBARENTRY(){

        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(2f, 0));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(4f, 1));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(8f, 3));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(7f, 4));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(3f, 5));

    }

    public void AddValuesToBarEntryLabels(){

        BarEntryLabels.add("January");
        BarEntryLabels.add("February");
        BarEntryLabels.add("March");
        BarEntryLabels.add("April");
        BarEntryLabels.add("May");
        BarEntryLabels.add("June");

    }



}
```

i tried Show at location property but it wont work. i google it. but cant find the answer. help me out with this .